# [HTML DOM].style undefinded? (html5 app: address book)

Tags: javascript, css, html

so basically I can't figure out why is giving me the folling error, when I call **add()** function (when you click on add button)...

it says: status.style is undefined
status is an html dom, an  html tag

I think the error is located almost at the end of the sheet

```js
var myArray = []; // * used to store all the data
myArray[0] = ['John', 'Doe', '1980'];
myArray[1] = ['Jane','Malloy','1982'];
myArray[2] = ['Vincent','Malloy','1988'];

var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var secondName = document.getElementById('secondName');
var bornYear = document.getElementById('bornYear');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
var status = document.getElementById('status');

var add = function() { //calls statusMessagge()
 
 // check if input[] its not empty...
 if ( firstName.value.length>0 && secondName.value.length>0 && bornYear.value.length>0 ) {
  // * adding inputs to myArray
  myArray[myArray.length] = [firstName.value ,secondName.value ,bornYear.value ];
  //clearBoxes();
  // * status messagge
  statusMessagge('good');
  alert('is good');
 }
 else {
  statusMessagge('bad');
  alert('is bad');
 }
};

var statusMessagge = function(arg) { // * it is been called by: add(), show()
 
 // * selecting the messagge to appear
 switch (arg) {
  case 'good':
   status.innerHTML = 'Person added successfully.';
   break;
  case 'bad':
   status.innerHTML = 'Please fill all the fields.';
   break;
  case 'loading':
   status.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
   break;
  case 'loaded':
   status.innerHTML = 'Finish.';
   break;
 }
 
 // * do opacity effect slow: show|hide
 status.style.opacity = 1; // this is the part that I get the error.
 setTimeout (function() {
  status.removeAttribute('style');
 }, 1000);
};
```

```css
body {
 background: lightgray;
 font-family: consolas;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
main {
 background: #dbcdcd;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
form:nth-of-type(1) {
 float: left;
}
form:nth-of-type(2) {
 float: left;
}
label { /* for alining elements correctly */
 display: inline-block;
 width: 77px;
 text-align: right;
}
input[type="text"]:not(:first-of-type) {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
#status {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .20s;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es-ES">
 <head>
  <title>.:_My Exercise_:.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <form id="form1" action=""> <!--action="#"  onsubmit="return false"-->
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Please introduce new person...</legend>
     
     <label>firstName:</label>
     <input id="firstName" type="text" autofocus tabindex="1"/>
     <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/> <br/>
     
     <label>secondName:</label>
     <input id="secondName" type="text" tabindex="2"/>
     <input type="button" value="Show" onclick="show()"/> <br/>
     
     <label>bornYear:</label>
     <input id="bornYear" type="text" tabindex="3"/>
     <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="sort()"/>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   
   <form>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Sort...</legend>
     <input type="button" value="a-z" onclick=""/>
     <input type="button" value="z-a" onclick=""/>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   
   <p id="status"></p>
   
   <p id="output"></p>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach:

I run your code on chrome, with one difference: run script.js after event '**DOMContentLoaded**', the event holds your script until browser informs that loaded all html:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

var myArray = []; // * used to store all the data
myArray[0] = ['John', 'Doe', '1980'];
myArray[1] = ['Jane','Malloy','1982'];
myArray[2] = ['Vincent','Malloy','1988'];

var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var secondName = document.getElementById('secondName');
var bornYear = document.getElementById('bornYear');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
var status = document.getElementById('status');

window.add = function() { //calls statusMessagge()
 
 // check if input[] its not empty...
 if ( firstName.value.length>0 && secondName.value.length>0 && bornYear.value.length>0 ) {
  // * adding inputs to myArray
  myArray[myArray.length] = [firstName.value ,secondName.value ,bornYear.value ];
  //clearBoxes();
  // * status messagge
  statusMessagge('good');
  alert('is good');
 }
 else {
  statusMessagge('bad');
  alert('is bad');
 }
};

var statusMessagge = function(arg) { // * it is been called by: add(), show()
 
 // * selecting the messagge to appear
 switch (arg) {
  case 'good':
   status.innerText = 'Person added successfully.';
   break;
  case 'bad':
   status.innerText = 'Please fill all the fields.';
   break;
  case 'loading':
   status.innerText = 'Loading...';
   break;
  case 'loaded':
   status.innerText = 'Finish.';
   break;
 }
 
 // * do opacity effect slow: show|hide
 status.style.opacity = 1; // this is the part that I get the error.
 setTimeout (function() {
  status.removeAttribute('style');
 }, 1000);
};
});
```

In function **statusMessagge()** you assign status with string, so it isn't html element anymore.
Try do:

```
status.innerText = 'some text';
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Even with innerText or innerHTML is still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to display a message in console. Use `console.log()` for that. It worked in `Firefox` for me.

Example:

```
// ... (your previous code)
if ( firstName.value.length>0 && secondName.value.length>0 && bornYear.value.length>0 ) {

    myArray[myArray.length] = [firstName.value ,secondName.value ,bornYear.value ];

    console.log("good");
    alert('is good');
}
else {
    console.log("bad");
    alert('is bad');
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed the element through to the `statusMessage` function allowing me to set it's innerHTML value.

We get the elements on the time of click rather onload to prevent the variables to be undefined.

```js
var myArray = []; // * used to store all the data
myArray[0] = ['John', 'Doe', '1980'];
myArray[1] = ['Jane','Malloy','1982'];
myArray[2] = ['Vincent','Malloy','1988'];




var add = function() { //calls statusMessagge()
var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
var secondName = document.getElementById('secondName');
var bornYear = document.getElementById('bornYear');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
var status = document.getElementById('status');
 // check if input[] its not empty...
 if ( firstName.value.length>0 && secondName.value.length>0 && bornYear.value.length>0 ) {
  // * adding inputs to myArray
  myArray[myArray.length] = [firstName.value ,secondName.value ,bornYear.value ];
  //clearBoxes();
  // * status messagge
  statusMessage(status, 'good');
 }
 else {
  statusMessage(status, 'bad');
 }
};

var statusMessage = function(element, arg) { // * it is been called by: add(), show()
    element.style.opacity = 1;
 switch (arg) {
  case 'good':
   element.innerHTML = 'Person added successfully.';
            break;
  case 'bad':
   element.innerHTML = 'Please fill all the fields.';
            break;
  case 'loading':
   element.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
            break;
  case 'loaded':
   element.innerHTML = 'Finish.';
            break;
        default:
            element.innerHTML = "";
            break;
 }
 // * do opacity effect slow: show|hide

 setTimeout (function() {
  element.removeAttribute('style');
 }, 1000);
};
```

```css
body {
 background: lightgray;
 font-family: consolas;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
main {
 background: #dbcdcd;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
form:nth-of-type(1) {
 float: left;
}
form:nth-of-type(2) {
 float: left;
}
label { /* for alining elements correctly */
 display: inline-block;
 width: 77px;
 text-align: right;
}
input[type="text"]:not(:first-of-type) {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
#status {
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity .20s;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es-ES">
 <head>
  <title>.:_My Exercise_:.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <form id="form1" action=""> <!--action="#"  onsubmit="return false"-->
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Please introduce new person...</legend>
     
     <label>firstName:</label>
     <input id="firstName" type="text" autofocus tabindex="1"/>
     <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/> <br/>
     
     <label>secondName:</label>
     <input id="secondName" type="text" tabindex="2"/>
     <input type="button" value="Show" onclick="show()"/> <br/>
     
     <label>bornYear:</label>
     <input id="bornYear" type="text" tabindex="3"/>
     <input type="button" value="Sort" onclick="sort()"/>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   
   <form>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Sort...</legend>
     <input type="button" value="a-z" onclick=""/>
     <input type="button" value="z-a" onclick=""/>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   
   <p id="status"></p>
   
   <p id="output"></p>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```